# Standard scrollbars in Sublime Text 3

Tags: scrollbar, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is there any way to have standard Windows/system native scrollbars in Sublime Text 3 or do I have to get myself used to these tiny little ones?

For me, a person with medium eyes problems, current scrollbars are just to tiny and I'm having problems, from time to time, with catching them. I heard, that *eveything* is configurable in Sublime Text 3, so I'd like to ask, if scrollbars can be changed as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Miles Zhang suggests,

> you can try some third part themes
>   ... you can find more themes from Package Control

And you can change the size of the scroll-bars for most of them as well.  Create a file in your packages directory with the same name as your theme.
I like to use [Cyanide](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20Cyanide) theme, so I would create a new file in (packages dir)/User/Cyanide.sublime-theme.  then set the attributes you want.  In this case, you want to set scroll_bar_control : content_margin.
My Cyanide.sublime-theme file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "class": "scroll_bar_control",
        "attributes": ["horizontal"],
        "content_margin": [3, 4] //makes horiz scrollbar taller
    },
    {
        "class": "scroll_bar_control",
        "content_margin": [1, 3] //makes vert scrollbar taller
    },
    {
        "class": "tab_label",
        "parents": [{"class": "tab_control", "attributes": ["selected"]}],
        //"fg": [30,30,30],
        "fg": [255,131,0] //change highlighted tab color
    }
]
```

Most of my info was learned [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150812071949/http://sublimetext.userecho.com:80/topic/116003-make-the-scrollbar-markerindicator-more-visible)

Comment: you can also use the "large_scroll_bars" setting in the Cyanide theme :) https://github.com/lefoy/cyanide-theme#large-scrollbars

Comment: I tried getting the https://packagecontrol.io/installation  and then opening Tools/Commandpalatte, entering: "Package Control: Install Package" and then choosing Cyanide. Then I wrote that file and restarted sublime. My scrollbars still disappear. I also rechecked Show/ViewConsole to see if there were any errors on restart. Btw the cut/paste python gives a tab error using this page's 'auto' installer; https://packagecontrol.io/installation

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can change the scrollbars to system native style, but you can try some third part themes that with bright color scheme.

For example: [Numix Theme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Numix%20Theme). You can find more themes from [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/).

Comment: Accepting, though _brightness_ or _color_ isn't a problem for me. I was rather reffering to be able to change **size** of the scrollbars (i.e. make them bigger, just as system ones).